# Can I install windows drivers on a acer one 10 s1003 2gb model that runs lubuntu as main os?

Tags: networking, drivers, lubuntu, acer

I want to install some acer one 10 s1003 factory drivers on lubuntu, because this machine doesn't have any. Well, I was trying to install a linux distros these days, I tested fedora, but unfotunately wi-fi didn't work and I couldn't solve that problem. For that reason I tried to install lubuntu, that distro runned pretty well in that machine, except for the Network Manager failed to start. I tried to fix it with a script, it didn't work either, in that moment I was frustrated and I just tried to install ubuntu in my machine. During the installation process ubuntu installer found an error which stopped the instalation process. I restarted my machine and noticed that the internal storage was empty, Lubuntu was eliminated from the main storage, obvously my machine won't boot. I reinstalled lubuntu, but I realiced that my machine had no factory drivers. Now my machine doesn't have network drivers, sound drivers, gyroscope drivers and others, and realice this because lubuntu didn't detect the wi-fi card of my machine when I checked the hardware. Something weird happened after these drivers were erased, for some weird reason I could connect my machine to the internet through an rj-45/usb adapter, before these trouble I couldn't due to failed network manager.

Well I want to install a linux distro due to: windows is too demanding for the hardware of that machine.

Thanks everybody for your answers, sorry for my englsh.

Immaplane

Edit: The system that I installed on my machine is Lubuntu 20.04, sorry everyone, I forgot give you that information

Comment: You cannot install Windows drivers. Have you updated UEFI firmware to latest available? See these for a possible fix. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1274034/unable-to-use-wifi-driver-after-changing-of-efi-path-on-acer-one-10-s1003d16h1 & https://askubuntu.com/questions/566130/ubuntu-does-not-detect-wifi-bt-combo-card-bcm4330-ap6383 & https://github.com/Spiffyk/acer-one-10-fixes

Comment: I think, I have the latest UEFI version available on my tablet, because I tried to flash it on my machine with the insyde h20 assistant when my machine was running windows, this assistant showed a message that told me that version had been flased on the bios already. I was checking briefly those links, Well I tried the script but It didn't work, I don't know if I forget a step that allows that script works, I'm pretty new in this linux world and these stuff is pretty complex to me I need to learn a lot haha. The method on the other link, I haven't tried it yet.  Thanks anyways for your answer.

Comment: Please also provide details as to what release you're using. Ubuntu releases (which include Lubuntu) use the *year.month* format which is a very huge clue was to the age of the software stack; as software on consumer devices usually gets written after the release of the hardware (unless device is initially advertized with device which is usually enterprise grade for GNU/Linux), and *drivers* being kernel modules are tied to the kernel in use; but you gave no details as to what software stack you're wanting to use (ie. release details and be specific with LTS which has two stack choices).

Comment: sorry @guiverc, the release is lubuntu 20.04, I forgot that detail, I'm new in this world of linux

Comment: Lubuntu 20.04 & 20.04.1 media uses the GA or 5.4 kernel (early 2020 kernel stack), however Lubuntu 20.04.2 media defaults to the HWE kernel which currently is 5.8 (will soon bump to 5.11).  You'll have to look at what hardware your box is using (`sudo lshw -C network` for example will list-hardware of class networking which may provide some clues on networking hardware issues).

Comment: Well I'm about to try that, thanks

Comment: Well, I tried to look the hardware, infortunately, the system doesn't show any network hardware

Comment: Low end consumer devices are usually made for price and constantly change thus *drivers* are ignored. I'll provide https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/WirelessTroubleShootingGuide where in Step 3 is the *Device Recognition and Operation* step - that is key to solving the issue, as you have to identify your networking chipset to make it work (GNU/Linux is developed to work with chipsets, not brand/model on the outside-case)

Comment: Thanks @guiverc for the guide, I will follow it. If I hope finding a solution